# Verify whether a multiset is the union of the subset sum of another multiset

Tags: algorithm, verification, subset-sum

I want to figure out an algorithm to verify whether a multiset is the union of the subset sum of another multiset, but I failed after struggling for several hours by myself.

The details is as follows:

Multiset A: A postive integer set

Multiset B: A postive integer set (smaller than or equal to A, later you will know why)

Algorithm function: Verify whether for all numbers in B, one number or sum of numbers in A can match them. Each number in A can only be used once and all numbers in A have to be used. All numbers in B must be matched.

An example to clear this up: 
Suppose multiset A = {1, 3, 4, 4, 6} , B = {5, 6, 7}

Then the algorithm will output "TRUE", because 5 is a sum of 1 and 4, 6 is equal to 6, 7 is the sum of 3 and 4. Meanwhile all numbers in A are used and used only once, while all numbers in B ared checked.

But for A = {2, 6, 8}, B = {7, 9}, the algorithm will output "FALSE", although 2+6+8 = 7+9, but none number in B is sum of numbers in A.

Some notes:

1 Known conditions, the sum of numbers in A is equal to the sum of numbers in B.

2 As the examples show, a certain number can appear multiple times.

3 Each number in the multiset can only be used once, so if 3 is used in one solution (to get 7), it can not be used again in another solution. The number 4 appears twice, so it can be used in two solutions.

4 Multiple solutions for one number are possible, (like 7 can be 1 and 6 or it can be 3 and 4), but some (like 7 can be 1 and 6) maybe wrong in the veryfication process.

5 Multiset A is not large, at most 30 elements

I try my best but my solution always can't cover all conditions of multiset A and B. I thought the solution to this is apparently beyond me.

So, I really need your clever people's help. Please help me. Any answer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The use of the term 'set' seems inappropriate. Sets traditionally do not allow for repeated elements. Set A in your example should be called a multiset or bag.

Comment: Oh, sorry for my negligence! Thanks. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

It is NP-complete problem (reduction to "subset sum problem" is very simple). 
So there is no efficient solution to this problem.

You can see different ways to solve it here :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

**The naive algorithm :**

```
naiveAlg(A,B) :
  for each partition P of A such that |P| = |B| do :
    for each element E in P do :
      calculate the sum of E numbers and store in E'
    if E' is equal to B return true
  return false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact I know the SSP and it's DP resolution. But the key is that my problem is more global than SSP if you have read the post carefully. And with the conditions(elements are all positive),  I think an uncomplecated algorithm should be there. I don't care whether the algorithm is polynomial because the nuber of the multiset is less than 40. I just want the idea. More advice?

Comment: SSP with positive numbers is in NPC as well, so the general version of your problem (i.e without condition 5) is hard either. If you don't care about efficiency - use naive algorithm(see my edited answer)